# javascript gzip compression

Tags: apache, compression, gzip

I am using the following code in my `.htaccess` file kept in the server root to enable `gzip` compression. However, the javascript is not getting compressed.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/plain text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/x-httpd-php
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>
```

How to enable compression of javascript? I have checked that mod_deflate is enabled and the index page is getting compressed.
My website is hosted [here](http://www.interface14.in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are not treating javascript as a simple text file here. `text/javascript` should be replaced by `application/javascript` as shown.

`Application/x-javascript` was used for IE as it ignored scripts.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/plain text/xml application/javascript         application/x-javascript application/x-httpd-php
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>
```

Cheers!